# Counting char in word with different delimiter

Tags: shell, count, delimiter

I am writing a shell script, in which I get the location of java via which java. As response I get (for example)

`/usr/pi/java7_32/jre/bin/java`.

I need the path to be cut so it ends with /jre/, more specificly

```
/usr/pi/java7_32/jre/
```

as the programm this information is provided to can not handle the longe path to work.

I have used cut with the / as delimiter and as I thought that the directory of the Java installation is always the same, therfore a

```
cut -d'/' -f1-5
```

worked just fine to get this result:

```
/usr/pi/java7_32/jre/
```

But as the java could be installed somewhere else aswell, for example at

```
/usr/java8_64/jre/
```

the statement would not work correctly.

I need tried sed, awk, cut and different combinations of them but found no answer I liked.

As the title says I would count the number of appereance of the car `/` until the substing `jre/` is found under the premisse that the shell counts from the left to the right.

The incremented number would be the the field I want to see by cutting with the delimiter.

```
path=$(which java) # example: /usr/pi/java7_32/jre/bin/java
i=0

#while loop with a statment which would go through path

while substring != jre/ {

  if (char = '/') 
    i++
}

#cut the path 
path=$path | cut -d'/' -f 1-i  

#/usr/pi/java7_32/jre result
```

Problem is the eventual difference in the path before and after

```
/java7_64/jre/, like   */java*/jre/
```

I am open for any ideas and solutions, thanks a lot!

Greets
Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the shell's built-in parameter operations to get what you need. (This will save the need to create other processes to extract the information you need).

```
jpath="$(which java)"
# jpath now /usr/pi/java7_32/jre/bin/java

echo ${jpath%jre*}jre
```

produces

```
/usr/pi/java7_32/jre
```

The same works for

```
jpath=/usr/java8_64/jre/
```

The `%` indicates remove from the right side of the string the matching shell reg-ex pattern. Then we just put back `jre` to have your required path.

You can overwrite the value from `which java`

```
jpath=${jpath%jre*}jre
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You can get the results with grep:

```
path=$(echo $path | grep -o ".*/jre/")
```